# Cannot get local candidate for WebRTC in iOS safari

Tags: ios, safari, webrtc

I only want to transfer data though WebRTC, so I didn't add `addStream` to `RTCPeerConnection`. What I need is `"sdpMid":"data"` local wlan candidates.

When in local WIFI network, the `onicecandidate` event won't return a local candidate in iOS 11 Safari.

When using a STUN server, it can return a remote candidate, but still no local candidate.

How to fix this?

--------------------------- UPDATE ----------------------------------------

I have to use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})` to activate local candidate...
Only with this command, then iOS Safari can get the local candidate and open channel in LAN environment.

Don't know if it's an iOS bug.

Comment: can you post a list of all your candidates?

Comment: @Rubycon yes, the result is NONE []. I can get 0 candidates when using 0 iceServers where chrome can get the local candidate.

Comment: how it works at Safari desktop?

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended behaviour as explained in the Webkit blog: https://webkit.org/blog/7763/a-closer-look-into-webrtc/

Comment: So even if i only want to transfer data though WebRTC, I still need to `getUserMedia` in webkit, right? Why don't we need to do this in chrome?

Comment: add a stun server and hope the NAT does hairpinning correctly. In the future browsers might use MDNS in order not to leak local ip addresses but that is still work in progress.